# When Remote Debugging Quarkus with Intellij, how do you skip stepping into _SubClass$$function$$?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, quarkus

When Remote Debugging Quarkus with Intellij, how do you skip stepping into _SubClass$$function$$?

The remote debugger connects without issue and breakpoints trigger.

But stepping into a function call in my own code, I end up in endless _SubClass and _ClientProxy classes (in the debug stack) with no matching code.

I can go to Intellij settings and add patterns for "*_Subclass" and "*_ClientProxy" and "*_Bean" to "Do not step into the classes".

This helps alot, but there area still numerous entries with "_SubClass$$function$$" that aren't skipped.

Example of stack entry that is still a problem:

`<init>:49, BusinessPartnerLogicImpl_Subclass$$function$$2`

Comment: For now it's working to add 10 lines to the ignored classes "*_Subclass$$function$$0" to "*_Subclass$$function$$9". (While adding * instead of the number does NOT work, also ".*" incase it's regex also doesn't work.)

Comment: Can you configure IntelliJ to skip synthetic methods based on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/stepping-through-the-program.html#configure-stepping?

Comment: good idea @geoand, sadly this option is already active. (I think that maybe the methods are not actually compiler generated, but runtime generated by quarkus...)